# Polygon vertices disappearing/merging when less than 5 ft apart in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing

I am having trouble with ArcGIS 10.2.2 on a database I received from a client.  Anytime I drawn a new polygon, if the vertices are closer than about 5 feet they will merge into one vertex at the midpoint of the line segment between the two vertices when completing the sketch (F2).  I have looked into possible topology issues but cannot find that topology has been enabled on the database.  The XY Tolerance is set to 0.0032 US Foot.  Snapping is set to 15 pixels and is working.

The sketch line looks fine with vertices at all locations needed.  Press F2 and the final polygon is changed as noted above.  No issues with lines that have vertices closer than 5 feet, just polygons.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I genuinely have no clue if this would even affect what your talking about, as I don't see why it would and haven't heard of any such experience before, but... maybe check if there is an issue with the edited data being in a different projection than the dataframe's projection and the translation is causing this...??? Again, not sure why that would be the case, but translation issue was the first thought that came to mind to possibly explain that oddity.  Good luck.

Comment: There is a 'Domain, Resolution, and Tolerance' setting at the Feature Class level in FGB and PGB. Have you checked this?

Comment: I would double check what John suggested, as well as trying to use a fresh mxd and only including the layer you are editing (and whatever else is essential).

Comment: I double checked the projection, resolution and tolerance for the database(SQL), datasets and feature classes and all are the same.  Creating a new MXD with one of the problematic feature classes does work correctly when drawing a new feature.  However, I was really hopping I would not need to rebuild the entire MXD as it is massive.  I remember having an issue something like this a few years ago but cannot remember the fix.

Comment: I guess you could try running the MXD doctor program against is... no guarantees that would fix it, but, I guess worth a try.  (Should be in Start Menu> All Programs > ArcGIS > Desktop Tools > MXD Doctor, or at least that's where it is on my system).  That can sometimes fix corrupted MXD's, so might be worth a try.  Also, I know you said all the data is the same projection, but just double checking, did you make sure the projection of all the data was the same as the one set for the dataframe in the MXD itself.  (Dataframe > Properties > Coordinate System tab).

Comment: Got it.  I created layer files for each layer group, opened a new blank mxd and set the data frame to the correct coordinate system, dragged the layer files into the TOC and saved the new mxd.  Everything is working for the moment.  John, can you post an answer to create a new MXD and I will except it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my initial thought would be that it is a resolution or topology type issue, but as you said you have checked both of these, my next thought would be it sounds like either a projection/translation issue and/or a corrupted MXD issue.  I would suggest starting with checking that the projection of the data being edited matches the projection of the dataframe it is in within the MXD (Dataframe > Properties > Coordinate System tab).  If the projections match, then I would try making a copy of the MXD and running MXD Doctor application on it and see if it is a corrupted MXD issue that MXD Doctor can resolve (Should be in Start Menu> All Programs > ArcGIS > Desktop Tools > MXD Doctor, or at least that's where it is on my system).  If nothing so far has helped though, as always with ArcGIS Desktop, try creating a new MXD and add the same data in (checking and making sure you set the dataframe to the correct projection to match the data's) and see if you experience the same issue.  If a new MXD solves it, then you should be able to go back to the original MXD and bring in the layers by copying them in and/or saving the layers (or layer groups) out as layer files and bring those layer files into the new MXD.

Unfortunately, if you are still experiencing this issue after all of that, I would have to suggest calling ESRI Tech Support as it would seem that would almost have to be a software bug they should be aware of.